# How to programmatically get current sorted column in Devextreme datagrid?

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I use devextreme datagrid 17.1.1 version in my Angular 4 project.
I want get current sorted column in typeScript, but datagrid's instance hasn't sorting field.
How can I get current sorted column ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reading the `sortIndex` of a column. It will be 0 or 1 depending on how many columns are sorted. If you only have one column sorted at a time you can do something like this:

```js
@ViewChild(DxDataGridComponent, { static: false }) dataGrid: DxDataGridComponent;

getSortedColumn() {
  const instance = this.dataGrid.instance;
  const allColumns = Array.from(Array(instance.columnCount()).keys()).map(index => instance.columnOption(index));
  return allColumns.find(col => col.sortIndex != null);
}
```

Comment: If I hide a column with columnChooser, getVisibleColumns will not return the column, therefore I will not get sorted column (

Comment: It is wokring for me, but I did small change in your code. Thanks